# Connect Redis using Unix socket

Tags: cache, cm-redissession

I already installed Redis on a Centos server. I have updated the file etc/redis.conf with the following config:

unixsocket /var/run/redis/redis.sock

unixsocketperm 777

$ redis-cli ping returns "PONG" so basically Redis is working. But I still can't connect from my Magento application. Here is my config on app/etc/local.xml

```
<config>
<global>
    <install><date>...</date></install>
    <crypt><key>...</key></crypt>
    <cache>
        <backend>Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis</backend>
        <backend_options>
            <server>/var/run/redis/redis.sock</server>
            <port>0</port>
            <database>0</database>
            <password></password>
            <force_standalone>0</force_standalone>
            <connect_retries>1</connect_retries>
            <read_timeout>10</read_timeout>
            <automatic_cleaning_factor>0</automatic_cleaning_factor>
            <compress_data>1</compress_data>
            <compress_tags>1</compress_tags>
            <compress_threshold>20480</compress_threshold>
            <compression_lib>gzip</compression_lib>
            <persistent></persistent>
            <use_lua>0</use_lua>
        </backend_options>
    </cache>
    <disable_local_modules>false</disable_local_modules>
    <resources>...</resources>
    <session_save>db</session_save>
    <redis_session>                       
        <host>/var/run/redis/redis.sock</host>          
        <port>0</port>
        <password></password>        
        <timeout>2.5</timeout>            
        <persistent></persistent>         
        <db>0</db>                      
        <compression_threshold>2048</compression_threshold>  
        <compression_lib>gzip</compression_lib>              
        <log_level>1</log_level>               
        <break_after_frontend>5</break_after_frontend>       
        <fail_after>10</fail_after>                         
        <break_after_adminhtml>30</break_after_adminhtml>
        <first_lifetime>600</first_lifetime>                 
        <bot_first_lifetime>60</bot_first_lifetime>          
        <bot_lifetime>7200</bot_lifetime>                    
        <disable_locking>0</disable_locking>                 
        <min_lifetime>60</min_lifetime>                      
        <max_lifetime>2592000</max_lifetime>                
    </redis_session>
</global>
<admin>...</admin>
```

Any thoughts? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try remove below line:

```
<session_save>db</session_save>
```

In my local.xml, before adding redis code, there is already ***session_save*** tag:

```
<session_save><![CDATA[db]]></session_save>
```

IMHO, I think adding redis code created a duplicate of session tags. After removing the ***session_save*** tag going with redis code, my site was working again. This is my workaround. Maybe it just works in my case.